# Can a python dictionary be created and updated on the go

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to create a nested dictionary on the go inside a for loop. I have the parent dictionary `data` initialized to empty. Now inside the loop, I get the key to be added to the parent dictionary. And each key being again a dictionary.

```
data = {}
for condition
    Get x, y     # x is the new key 
    if x not in data:
        data[x] ={}
        data[x].update({y:1})    # or data[x][y] = 1
```

But I want to do the above piece in one line as below

```
data = {}
for condition
    Get x, y  # x is the new key 
    if x not in data:
        data.update({x:{}}.update({y:1}))
```

Here I am getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. I guess this is due to the inner update (i.e. `update({y:1}`) is getting executed first and trying to update `x` which is not yet present, hence `NoneType`.

Is there any other way I can achieve this in one line? Or do I have the only way to create an empty dictionary first and then update the same as shown in first code piece ?

Comment: Could you provide some actual data for examples?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do automatic nested dictionary insertion? If so, you could try using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(dict)
for i in range(10):
    x = "..."
    y = "..."
    data[x][y] = 1

print data["..."]["..."]
```

This prints `1`

Comment: Or with plain `dict`, `data.setdefault(x, {})[y] = 1`. Generally less efficient than `defaultdict(dict)`, because it needs to create an empty `dict` to pass as an argument even if the default goes unused (and because method calls are more expensive than raw `dict` getitem operations), but it's good to know about `setdefault` when you need to do a mix of operations, some of which add a default if missing, while others raise `KeyError` as normal.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be achieved `data[x] = {y :1}` or `data.update({x: {y:1})` as mentioned by @karthikr